# Разбиение строки на группы в регулярных выражениях

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Хочу проверить строку на наличие хаотически выставленных букв разных регистров. Для примера строка на входе:

> Это стрОка... это сТроКа.

Выходная строка:

> Это строка... Это строка.

Установку первой буквы предложения делаю так:

```
private static final String DOT_REGEX = "\\s*(?<!\\.)\\.(?!\\.)\\s*";
private static final String MULTI_DOT_REGEX = "\\s*\\.{3}\\s*";
private static final String FORMAT_CASE = "(?:^| )^\\w" + "|" + MULTI_DOT_REGEX + "\\w" + "|" + DOT_REGEX + "\\w";
```

Функция которая обрабатывает строку и возвращает готовый результат:

```
private static String getFormatCaseString(String targetString){
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(FORMAT_CASE).matcher(targetString);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        while (matcher.find()){
            matcher.appendReplacement(stringBuffer, matcher.group().toUpperCase());
        }
        matcher.appendTail(stringBuffer);
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }
```

Идея в том что бы разбить предложение на две группы: первая это первые буквы нового предложения (которые и устанавливаются в `UpperCase`) и вторая это все остальные буквы которые выставляются в нижнем регистре. Как это сделать?

Comment: Может, https://ideone.com/nqgh7i?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, спасибо еще раз Вам. Не могли бы вы еще раз в ответе объяснить данное выражение. Тяжко мне даются регулярные выражения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете захватить первую букву (символ типа word) в первую захватывающую группу и весь текст до первой одиночной точки или троеточия в другую группу, а дальше применить имеющуюся логику для замены:

```
String targetString = "Это стрОка... это сТроКа.";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?Us)(\\w)(.*?(?:\\.{3}|(?<!\\.)\\.(?!\\.)))").matcher(targetString);
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

while (matcher.find()){
    matcher.appendReplacement(stringBuffer, 
        matcher.group(1).toUpperCase() + 
        matcher.group(2).toLowerCase()
    );
}
matcher.appendTail(stringBuffer);
System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
// = Это строка... Это строка.
```

**Подробности**

- `(?Us)` - модификаторы `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` (чтобы `\w` находил и русские буквы) и `Pattern.DOTALL` (чтобы `.` находил символы перевода строки)
- `(\\w)` - Захватывающая группа №1: буква, цифра или `_` (это значение будет приведено к верхнему регистру - `matcher.group(1).toUpperCase()`)
- `(.*?(?:\\.{3}|(?<!\\.)\\.(?!\\.)))` - Захватывающая группа №2 (это значение будет приведено к нижнему регистру - `matcher.group(2).toLowerCase()`):

  - `.*?` - 0 и более любых символов, как можно меньше
  - `(?:` - начало незахватывающей группы

    - `\\.{3}`  - три точки
    - `|` - или
    - `(?<!\\.)\\.(?!\\.)` - точка, перед и за которой нет других точек
  - `)` - конец незахватывающей группы